# How to change protocol - ftp to http in Requestly chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, url-rewriting, requestly

Is it possible to add a protocol in a search of "Redirect Request Rule" wanting to go from an "ftp:" to an "https:"?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [Requestly Chrome/Firefox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/reviews). You can use [Replace Rule](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/16/replace-rule-documentation/) to achieve this.

Here are the steps -

1. Create New Replace Rule
2. Replace "ftp:" With "http:"
3. URL Contains "example.com"

[image]